# File stream with repeating input

Tags: c++, do-while, ifstream

I'm attempting to create a repeating menu that will allow a user to re-enter a file name if the program is unable to open the file.

Right now it works correctly if I enter the name of an existing file, but if the file doesn't exist it prints the "File not found" then executes the rest of the program. I'm new to file streams and most of the code here was found through references. I'm a bit lost on what exactly is going on and what the best way to handle the situation is. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
typedef istream_iterator<char> istream_iterator;    

string fileName;

ifstream file;

do {        
    cout << "Please enter the name of the input file:" << endl;
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream file(fileName.c_str());

    if (!file) {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
    }

} while (!file);

std::copy(istream_iterator(file), istream_iterator(), back_inserter(codeInput));
```

Comment: You're declaring a variable inside your loop with the same name as the external file. Change `ifstream file (fileName.c_str());` to `file = std::ifstream(fileName);` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code will work.

```
do {
    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the input file:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> fileName;

    file = std::ifstream(fileName.c_str());

    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
    }

} while (!file);
```

your error was that you have 2 definition of the file variable. 
the variable in `while (!file)` that is used is the one defined outside the do-while loop, and it is valid state is set to true by default.

Answer (score 3):

After constructing the object `file` will always exist, so your loop condition always fails. Change the condition to whether the file didn't open properly.

```
do {
...
}
while (!file.is_open())
```

Comment: Please unaccept my answer, it's more wrong than right, Arkady Godlin's answer below is more deserving of being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @acraig5075 answer:

Writing a type then a variable name (`ifstream file`) is to create a new variable. Obviously you know this, but if you use the same name again in, for example, a loop, it makes a new and distinct variable.

```
ifstream file; // a unique variable
...
do {
    ...
    ifstream file(fileName.c_str()); // another unique variable
```

...so change the usage inside the loop to:

```
    file.open(fileName.c_str());
```